# Recover unversioned files removed by SVN clenaup

Tags: svn, windows-10, tortoisesvn, netbeans-8

Unfortunately I deleted all unversioned file form my NetBeans project by SVN cleanup command by TortoiseSVN. How can I revert or undo file deletion?

Comment: If they're unversioned, you can't revert, becaues they're not there to revert. SVN does not use the recycle bin, so you can't get them from there either. Most likely you're out of luck unless you have a backup from which you can restore them.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your quick response.... i found a solution...!

Comment: I missed that you were using TSVN instead of just SVN. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use TortoiseSVN for cleanup command. according to  TortoiseSVN user-friendly design it  doesn't just delete files but first moves them to the Windows recycle bin (trash folder).

so that i found all delete file in the Windows recycle bin and restore them from there.

[tortoiseSVN Recycle Bin](https://tortoisesvn.net/recyclebin.html)